# Will notification Content extension required new provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, provisioning-profile

Can automatic sign in for Notification Content extension will work?

As of now i am creating new provisioning profile & selecting under **Signing(Debug) & Signing(release)**. Please tell me am i doing wrong ?

Screenshot for reference -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your using **Notification Context extension**, make sure Provisioning profile different for both Target as well as context extension.

Note point here, Bundle identifier for extension should be like below formate **com.teamName.mainbundleIdentifier.contextName**.

Suppose if your bundle identifier is this **com.myteam.abc** then bundle identifier for Notification Context extension should look like below.

**com.myteam.abc.notifyContext**

Answer (score 0):

Yes Automatic Signing will work, but only if you are an admin user in your developer account.

This is because only a admin user will be able register for a new app id(`for Notification Content Extension`) and behind the scene that's what Automatic Signing will do.

This is only if the you are trying to register for `Notification Content Extension` for the first time. Post registering once, all the users should be able to use the Automatic Signing option.